# Unable to retrieve cookie content by name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

[image]

As you can see, I have a cookie called "U_SESSION" that I made using Node.js.

Now I try to retrieve it in the client side, using JavaScript:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var session = getCookie("U_SESSION");

console.log(session);
```

The console logs an empty string (""). Why is this happening, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);` - that's your first mistake - don't do that on `document.cookies`

Comment: it doesn't do anything, still empty string

Comment: Your code actually works even with the decodeURIcomponent (I still wouldn't do that, by the way, it could mess up looking for cookies) - what does `console.log(document.cookie)` look like? can you see `U_SESSION` in there? if not, it could be that U_SESSION is a http-only cookie